# Is there a way to order the Authentication in IIS7.5?

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7.5, wcf-security

Can we have more than one authentication (anonymous, windows, forms, basic, etc) enabled in IIS at a time?

If two or more authentiation are enabled, what is the order by which authentications are handled?

And, if there is an order, how to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative.

If you had Basic + Anonymous enabled, Basic would take priority, and Anonymous would never be used if they failed Basic... understand?

"An important restriction that you should be aware of when enabling different authentication methods is that you can’t enable both a challenge-based and a logon redirection–based authentication method at the same time. In other words, you can’t enable forms authentication (which is redirection-based) while basic, digest, or Windows authentication (which are challenge-based) is also enabled."

http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/understanding-iis-70-authentication <-- Good read
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication#005

Comment: How about newer versions of IIS, like 8 and 8.5?

Comment: @blagus I don't see anything suggesting this has changed with 8